# Metpy Interpolate values for the given point

Tags: metpy

I use this Metpy interpolation methods  https://unidata.github.io/MetPy/latest/examples/gridding/Point_Interpolation.html#sphx-glr-examples-gridding-point-interpolation-py. My question is how do I get the interpolated temperature value for the given point, in this case from the image for the New York? So, I'm getting lat and lon and I get the temperature value at that point.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LsLgZ.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the example code, the data are being projected to a grid on an Albers Equal Area projection created with:

```
 import cartopy.crs as ccrs
 to_proj = ccrs.AlbersEqualArea(central_longitude=-97.0000, central_latitude=38.0000)
```

You can use `to_proj` to convert your lat/lon into projected coordinates using:

```
 pt_x, pt_y = to_proj.transform_point(lon, lat, ccrs.Geodetic())
```

You can then use `pt_x` and `pt_y` to find the closest indices in the `gx` and `gy` arrays (created in the original example code) to pull the data value out of the `img` array.

If you really only care about the value at a particular location, you might want to look at MetPy's [`interpolate_to_points`](https://unidata.github.io/MetPy/latest/api/generated/metpy.interpolate.interpolate_to_points.html#metpy.interpolate.interpolate_to_points) function.

Comment: This interpolate_to_points function works, i get values for defined coordinates! I tried this first option, but unsuccessfully. I get this error message:TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars. This is how I worked : pt_x, pt_y = to_proj.transform_point(gx, gy, ccrs.Geodetic())

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I fixed problem using this command :

```
proj = ccrs.PlateCarree()
to_proj = ccrs.Mercator()

back_to_lon = precx.ravel()
back_to_lat = precy.ravel()
back_to_prec = prec_p.ravel()

pt_x = proj.transform_points(to_proj,back_to_lon,back_to_lat,back_to_prec)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FNxAX.png)